# What is the difference between filed of view and receptive field?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

guys. I want to know difference between  filed of view and receptive field. I know both things are similar, but what is the difference?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are essentially different concepts. Field of view is a [term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_view) related to the theory of optics, which means a solid angle with a vertex in the center of entrance pupil.

On the other hand, receptive field is a term of neural networks (convolutional/transformers), that means the size of the region in the input that produces the feature in the output (read more [here](https://theaisummer.com/receptive-field/)).